# Google Chrome Sync disaster...All bookmarks disappeared

Tags: google-chrome, sync, bookmarks, restore

I have lost years of bookmarking resources, project file references, articles and knowledge bases as well as links to purchased courses and paid memberships (I can restore a few from registration emails but the rest is gone!)

I cannot find a recent backup file.
The only backup file I found is from 2018 where I had a similar thing but managed to restore it.

I cannot find any backup file (one would assume Google will backup any removed bookmarks if changed during syncing, but they didn't)

I don't know what to do.

Went through quite a few tutorials about how to get the old backup file, but I don't have any backup file!!!

I am very upset. But is there anything I can do?
Maybe there is something I can do to restore the old file?

Thanks for any help.

Dany

Comment: If there isn’t another device where you profile was synchronized with then you are out of luck.

Comment: You cannot get this information back without another source of backup. It would be worth your effort to determine what caused this and how you might back up in the future. Do you still have your 2018 backup (a year or so instead of years)

Comment: One idea would be to contact the _Google_ Corporation, @Dany Sh and ask them whether they still keep any recent copies of your data within their caches.

Comment: Thanks for answering guys.

Comment: Thanks for answering guys.
@Ramhound - I have one laptop and a cellphone that are connected to this gmail account - I assume that the sync from the cellphone (very few bookmarks) went over to my laptop, instead of the opposite (what determines which copy is the sync source???)

Comment: @John - Unfortunately, I don't seem to have another backup source - I do not know even what was the source it synced with - I assume it is the cellphone (why not the opposite??? laptop to cellphone)
I have the 2018 backup but for some reason, it seems like the browser overwrote on it with the same new synced bm

Answer (score 0):

Your bookmarks are encrypted, which means you need to enter your Google Sync password before Google will retrieve your encrypted data. If you changed your Google password after the first time you set up Google Sync, Google will not accept your current Google password even though you are able to use it for Gmail, etc.

[image: Google Sync]

If you turn off sync, you can still see your bookmarks, history, passwords, and other settings on your computer. If you make any changes, they won't be saved to your Google Account and synced to your other devices.

If you have forgotten your Google Sync password, there are two options, reset sync and don't reset sync.

- If you don't reset sync then it is possible that Google will not accept your current Google Account password if you changed it after the first time you set up Google Sync. If the password you are trying doesn't work, try your Google Account password or older passwords.
- If you reset sync Google will delete your saved bookmarks **which you don't want to do**, so you need to contact Google to request them to change your Google Sync password to be the same as your current Google Account password without deleting any of your stored Google Sync data from their servers.

There is a link to get help from Google at https://support.google.com/chrome/?p=settings_sync_error/. If you visit this link you will see the following webpage. Click the link which says *Fix issues with sync in Chrome* which is highlighted in the below screenshot. You need to click the *Fix problems* option in order to unfold the items that are highlighted in blue in the below screenshot.

[image: Google Chrome Help]

After visiting [Fix issues with sync in Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/9175737) visit [Google's Account Recovery](https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery) page.

Google Chrome has an option to export bookmarks to an HTML file that you can use to manually transfer your Chrome bookmarks to another web browser or to backup your Chrome bookmarks.